# How can i make clipped part layer-list using Android XML

Tags: android, xml, drawable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4xEV.png)

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
 </layer-list>
```

I want to make clipped part. How can I make the cropped piece above .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="27dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="27dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        />
</shape>
```

Modify this to be able to add a specific angle:

```
bottomLeftRadius
bottomRightRadius
topLeftRadius
topRightRadius
```